# Intent filter: intent.getData() returns null

Tags: android, image, android-intent, android-manifest, android-activity

I'm writing an image editor in Android. So far it has a single activity. From this activity, I can load an image using a menu option that calls the Gallery activity, and in onActivityResult I treat the received image to paint my canvas so I can edit it. This is working fine.

What I'd like to do now is making this activity callable from anywhere else, so instead of having to pick an image from inside the activity, I could just open the Gallery, pick a photo and send it to my app. But I can't figure out how.

On my manifest, I've put the following inside the `<activity>` tags:

```
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
   <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
</intent-filter>
```

Then, in my activity, as mentioned in http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/filters.html , I've put the following inside onCreate():

```
...
//after initializing my view and stuff

Intent intent =getIntent();
Uri image = intent.getData();

//code to do something with my uri
...
```

When I install the app in my phone and then open the Gallery, I can pick an image and using the "send" menu and my app will show up in the app list, but when I select it my app opens but ignores the image. It turns out that the uri I'm getting from `intent.getData()` is null, and I can't figure out why.

Am I doing anything wrong? Am I forgetting something? If you must know, I'm on stock Android 2.3 using the CoolIris gallery provided with it.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The Uri you want is in the bundle. I have tried below code and can get the Uri of the image
such as `content://media/external/images/media/1750`

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
Uri uri = (Uri)bundle.get(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
```

More information you can see the [ACTION_SEND](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SEND)

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you! So, is Google's documentation wrong or was I misreading something?

Comment: See the ACTION_SEND doc, it explain the `input` that you should focus.