# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.net.Uri.getLastPathSegment()' on a null object reference

Tags: firebase, android-image, firebase-storage

I'm trying to upload image to firebase storage after capturing it from phone camera but when I run my code, I get the above error. I have tried to check if the URI returned is null as shown in this line of code

`Toast.makeText(UploadImage.this, "YOUR URI IS NULL", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`

but the Toast message does not get displayed, but error is thrown in the line following the toast which is

`filepath = storageReference.child("PhotoModel").child(uri.getLastPathSegment());`

Below is my whole code,

```
public class UploadImage extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button mUploadImg;
private ImageView mImageView;
private StorageReference storageReference, filepath;
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_upload_image);
    storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

    mUploadImg = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnUploadImg);
    mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    mUploadImg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent Imgintent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(Imgintent, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);

        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        progressDialog.setMessage("Upload Image ...");
        progressDialog.show();

        Uri uri = data.getData();
        if (uri == null) {


            Toast.makeText(UploadImage.this, "YOUR URI IS NULL", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        filepath = storageReference.child("PhotoModel").child(uri.getLastPathSegment());
        filepath.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();

                Toast.makeText(UploadImage.this, "Uploading ...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(UploadImage.this, "Upload Failed...Check your Internet Connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
  }
 }
```

Someone help me figure out where the problem starts, because I can't really put a finger on it right now...

Comment: Looks like the issue is the same as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10386885/intent-filter-intent-getdata-returns-null

Answer (score 1):

Got a different way of implementing this functionality. Hope it helps someone.

***First:*** Inside ***onCreate*** method.
Assuming you already have your ***ImageButton***(that will invoke camera) and upload ***button***(to upload you image to firebase storage) defined in xml file, Initialize your *ImageButton*

```
/** Button for adding and Uploading image*/
    mUploadImg = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnUploadImg);
```

**Second:** Set a onclick listener for the ***Imagebutton***

```
        /** Capture Image save and pass it to an intent   */
    mUploadImg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent Imgintent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(Imgintent, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    });
```

**Third:** Outside your ***onCreate*** method, implement ***startActivityForResult*** I have used ***Bitmap*** not ***Uri***

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        //set the progress dialog
        progressDialog.setMessage("Uploding image...");
        progressDialog.show();

        //get the camera image
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
        byte[] databaos = baos.toByteArray();

        //set the image into imageview
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
      //String img = "fire"

        //Firebase storage folder where you want to put the images
        StorageReference storageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

        //name of the image file (add time to have different files to avoid rewrite on the same file)
        StorageReference imagesRef = storageRef.child(productname + new Date().getTime());
        //send this name to database
        //upload image
        UploadTask uploadTask = imagesRef.putBytes(databaos);
        uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                Toast.makeText(UploadImage.this, "Sending failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                productDownloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl().toString();
                 progressDialog.dismiss();
                }
        } );}
}
```

If this has helped you, remember to acknowledge my answer.